# 404 error returned from valid URL from Amazon Route 53

Tags: asp-classic, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I am trying to use Amazon's Route 53 server API from Classic ASP but when I post the request I get back `HTTP 404 Not Found` error even though the URL sent is valid if I paste it into a browser. Is Classic ASP not capable of calling Route 53 or is there an error in my code?

```vb
Dim linebreak, gmt, timestamp, urlparams, amazonserver, stringtosign, signature, signedURL, sha256
const versionDate="2009-07-01"
amazonserver="https://route53.amazonaws.com/2012-02-29/xxxxxxxxxx"
linebreak=chr(13)

const secretkey="my secret key"
gmt=DateAdd("H", 0, Now)

timestamp = return_RFC822_Date(Now(), "GMT")

set sha256=GetObject("script:"&Server.MapPath("sha256.wsc"))

stringtosign = timestamp

signature=sha256.b64_hmac_sha256(secretkey, stringtosign)

header = "AWS3-HTTPS AWSAccessKeyId=ky access id,Algorithm=HMANSHA256,Signature="&signature

Set sha256=nothing

signedURL=amazonserver&"/onca/xml?"&urlparams&"&Signature="&Server.URLEncode(signature)
response.write signedURL

Set xmlHttp = Server.Createobject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
xmlHttp.Open "POST", signedUrl, False
    response.write strURL&"<br>"
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "asp httprequest"
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Host", "route53.amazonaws.com"
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "content-type", "text/plain"
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "X-Amzn-Authorization", signature
xmlHttp.Send()
    if xmlHttp.Status >= 400 And xmlHttp.Status <= 599 Then
        response.write "Error Occurred : " & xmlHttp.Status & " - " & xmlHttp.statusText
    else
        getXML = xmlHttp.responseText
    end if

xmlHttp.abort()
set xmlHttp = Nothing
```

Comment: Where are you getting the values of 'urlparams'? if it is blank, then the querystring will begin with "&Signature"...

Comment: Actually it turns out that my spelling (or possibly typing) isn't up to much and I was actually passing a null string to the call.Not sure how I mark this as closed?

Comment: @williamsdb Leave an answer detailing what caused the problem, that way you can accept it earn rep and stop the question appearing as unanswered. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @Lankymart after more than two years I think I stand no chance of remembering what the outcome was, sorry.

Comment: @williamsdb Fair point, to be honest not sure what shot the question on to my radar being two years old. Whoops.